# iOS - Create a BaseViewController, BaseViewModel and a BaseViewModel delagate with generics in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am trying to create a BaseViewController which is going to initialize a BaseViewModel and the BaseViewController will be the delegate of BaseViewModel based on a BaseViewModelDelegate.

My code is as follows:

```
import Foundation

class BaseVC <VM: BaseVM>: NSObject {
    //MARK: - Properties
    var viewModel = VM()

}
/////////////////////////////////////
protocol BaseVMDelegate : class {
}

class BaseVM{
    weak var delegate : BaseVMDelegate?
    required init() {
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////

class LoginVC : BaseVC<LoginVM> {

}

class LoginVM : BaseVM {

}
```

Everything works fine here but as soon as I insert the logic for the Delegate I get a lot of errors. 
I am trying to accomplish this logic:

```
import Foundation

class BaseVC <VM: BaseVM<D:BaseVMDelegate>>: NSObject {
    //MARK: - Properties
    var viewModel = VM()

}
/////////////////////////////////////
protocol BaseVMDelegate : class {
}

class BaseVM <D : BaseVMDelegate> {
    weak var delegate : D?

    required init() {
        self.delegate = D
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////

class LoginVC : BaseVC<LoginVM<LoginVMDelegate>> {

}

protocol LoginVMDelegate : BaseVMDelegate {
    func emailLoginResponse(success:Bool)
}

class LoginVM <D : BaseVMDelegate>: BaseVM<D> {

}
```

Errors:

> Non-nominal type 'VM' does not support explicit initialization
>
> 'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'D'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound
>   Cannot assign value of type 'D.Type' to type 'D?'

Can you please point me to the direction? Is it even possible what I am trying to accomplish?